# AVL with duplicate keys

Tags: c#, binary-tree, avl-tree

I have an AVL tree and I want the repeated strings to appear to me that they have been repeated twice, for example:
Let's say I insert:

laptop
laptop
pencil
pencil
pencil
rubber
rubber

The console that should output:

laptop (2)
pencil(3)
and rubber (2)

So far I've only gotten this and it doesn't seem to work.

```
public int countNode()
{
    return countX;
}
private int CountNode (Node<T> tree, T item)
{
    if (tree == null)
        return 0;
    if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) == 0)
        return countX++;
    else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data)< 0)
        return countX++;
    else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) > 0)
        return countX++;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to achieve this with the AVL tree that I have:[The outcome that I want to have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSJYC.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSJYC.png

Comment: My position is that if your AVL tree can hold duplicate keys then there's something wrong with it :)

Comment: Right now my AVAL cannot contain two identical words but I want that when there are two identical words, for example, that I insert rubber twice so that rubber (2) appears in the console. A very good example of what I want to do is in this photo. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSJYC.png @500-InternalServerError

Comment: Why not augment your AVL node with a counter field, so that a duplicate will not result in multiple nodes, but with an increased counter property of that single node?